# Keyframes won't insert; Blender 2.91

Tags: keyframes

I have everything set up, my rigging is ready, but I cannot add the keyframes. Whether I'm on keyframe 0 or keyframe 80, when I press the 'i' button, a notice says 'keying failed to insert any keyframes'. The menu doesn't come up either. What do I do to fix it?

Comment: It’s frames zero or a frame 80. Is the armature in pose mode? You may have set your “keyring“ to some type of key frame that is not applicable for armatures.